# Parse.com - User lookup failing

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'm having an issue looking up other users in my Parse app. Historically, I used:

```
[[PFUser query] getObjectInBackgroundWithId:someUserObjectId
                                      block:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {


                                      }];
```

but often, it seems, that it fails. This is particularly sad because it's how i create social connections in my app.. I read that:

```
PFUser *user = [PFQuery getUserObjectWithId:someUserObjectId];
```

is safer, but since i can't really reproduce this lookup failure in the simulator (or any of my accounts).. I'm looking for confirmation that switching to getUserObjectWithId will resolve the lookup problem.

Has anyone had a similar issue, or solved this problem in a consistent way?

Thank you!

Comment: it *fails*? In what way? is the error set or is the object empty or does the completion block not get called?

Comment: i'm not sure what the error code is but it just fails lookup, in that the object passed back in nil. the ACLs are set up fine, in that all user objects are readable for all (not writeable, obvs) @luk2302